# pyodbc.connect Microsoft Access

Tags: python, ms-access

Below is the code used to read a Microsoft access database and it works:

```
inputs_conn_str = (
r’DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.acct)};’
r’DBQ=\\File\Path\database;’)
)
inputs_cnxn = pyodbc.connect(inputs_conn_str)
```

The database name is based on a date. Is it possible to input the date on top of the code and adjust the database name based on this date?

I tried separating the database name and input the database variable in the code. It’s not working.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to insert a date string into the filename string, is that right? You can use many string substitutions in python, but f strings are particularly nice:

```
date_str = "04_12_2023"

inputs_conn_str = (
    'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.acct)};'
    f'DBQ=\\File\Path\database_{date_str};'
)

inputs_cnxn = pyodbc.connect(inputs_conn_str)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This wasn’t working but it helped me find the solution. I used %s to replace the string.

Comment: I actually figured out how your code works. I had a misinterpretation. It works great and it’s better looking code than %s! Thank you so much